# google maps embed not showing layers I have within the map for selection

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-embed

I have a share:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pPt91pmN97vXiq2bNUAJ-CXXqus&usp=sharing
This works wonderful if you are signed into google.
I would like the same to occur when not signed in.
When I use the Embed this map:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1pPt91pmN97vXiq2bNUAJ-CXXqus" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

I get only the map title and nothing else works.
I want them to be able to check the places I have categorized.
They aren't even showing up.

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1pPt91pmN97vXiq2bNUAJ-CXXqus" width="640" height="480"></iframe>

Comment: Above is the iframe I mentioned.  Seems the 1st time I entered it was omitted in my initial question.

Comment: I had a div of a logo and it was disabling things.  RESOLVED

Answer (score 0):

add in your css for iframe:
display:block;
I know that is strange but it work

as I have

```
html code:
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1mEwMw6znzNq_kMcG7xmkqfuPDrI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

css code:
.flexible-container{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:855px;
    height:480px;
    padding:7px 0 20px 0;
    background:#4d6a79;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.80), 0px -1px 1px #fff;
    border-radius:7px;
}
.flexible-container iframe{
    width:855px;
    height:480px;
    border:0;
    display: block;
    }
```